# How can I make Angular Router reload for new sub-routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm creating an Angular app capable of displaying products on a website. When I click on a certain product, expected behaviour is that it takes me to the product-description component, and it does. However, within the product-description component, clicking on a related product changes the URL but leaves the page unchanged. What do I have to do to change that?

So far, I've tried setting 'pathMatch' to 'full' in the Routing Module. My router-outlet is in the root app.component file, and so far, navigation has worked through the entire app as expected.

Here is the route in the Routes array:

```js
{ path: 'product/:prod_id', component: ProductDescriptionComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Here is the Product Component heading that links to the ProductDescription Component

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/product', bag.prod_id]" class="link-a">{{bag.title}}</a>
```

There are no error messages when I click on the product.

Comment: can you show the function which bind the route params to `bag.pro_id`

Comment: @EthanVu here it is:
```[html]
<div *ngFor="let bag of item?.products">
      <a [routerLink]="['/product', bag.prod_id]" class="link-a">{{bag.title}}</a>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My router-outlet is in the root index.html file, this is your problem!

Your app component should have a router outlet, the index.html cannot render components.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And that is where the components for the route will render.

Here is a simple StackBlitz that implements routing.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: My mistake. The router-outlet actually _is_ in my app.component file. I've edited my question to reflect that. Thanks for pointing that out!